# Div pushed downwards

Tags: html, css

I made two divs that are centered in the page and each have a textarea. I want to add some content underneath the textarea, but inside the div, but the problem is when I add it, it pushes the second div downwards.

Why is it pushed?

```css
.note {
  display: inline-block;
  /*
#F3F389-galben
#96C0FF albastru
#94F1B6 verde
rosu#f40042
*/
  background-color: #f40042;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  resize: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#notes {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="notes">
  <div class="note">
    <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
    <div id="sometext">sometext</div>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your inline block elements are [vertically aligned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Syntax) relative to the baseline by default, meaning the bottoms of the content inside your elements are aligned.

Change the `vertical-align` style to something more appropriate:

```css
.note {
  vertical-align:top;
  display: inline-block;
  /*
#F3F389-galben
#96C0FF albastru
#94F1B6 verde
rosu#f40042
*/
  background-color: #f40042;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  resize: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#notes {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="notes">
  <div class="note">
    <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
    <div id="sometext">sometext</div>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: What does it mean that they are aligned to the baseline?

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` or `vertical-align: top;` on `.note` CSS class.